# Extract json parameter from request

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to extract json parameters from a request but I couldn't.
By getParameter method in servletRequest, I could just get the post parameter. The json parameters don't have any name so by request.getParameter("?") I can't fill the question mark

Comment: What do you mean by _json parameter_?

Comment: I mean something like this:
Content-Disposition: form-data; 

{   "user_id" : 1,   "value" : "Water",   "typeCode" : "Searched" }

Comment: That is part of a header. Retrieve the header and parse out the JSON.

Comment: if you don't know what is a header you should read servlet docs.

Comment: ^ or the HTTP specification.

Comment: It looks the spring doesn't like to get parameters from the request.

Comment: actually it is in the body of a request. My comment was just a sample. sorry for that

Comment: wonderful, at least you know about that :) if you post the code with example will be much better...

Comment: So the JSON is in the body? Just read the body (with one of many ways) and parse the JSON.

Comment: I tried to read it by getinputsream but the problem was that more than one times spring tried to use it and then I got an exception.

Comment: Then use another way, maybe `@RequestBody`.

Comment: Are you using Spring MVC? Paste your controller method (you can skip not relevant parts of methods body)

Comment: @armin did you try my suggestion?

Comment: the problem is that I want to use the request in a filter, not in the controller so I cant use @RequestBody

Answer (score 3):

If you have prepared a java class in the exact structure like the json, do:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public mycontrollerfunc(@RequestBody YourJsonClass body){}
```

If not, and you want the json as a string, do:

```
@RequestMapping(...)

public mycontrollerfunc(@RequestBody String body){}
```

**EDIT**
If you need to extract the request body (which is what you refer to as "Json Parameter") from a method who can't use `@RequestBody` and only has access to `HttpServletRequest`, you can do the following:

```
String jsonFromRequestBody = CharStreams.toString(request.getReader());
```

In this case, request has to be `HttpServletRequest`, so you might need to cast it if you're in a `Filter`, something like:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
```

Comment: the problem is that I want to use the request in a filter, not in the controller so I cant use @RequestBody

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. To get the json from the request, you must use requestbody

Comment: I want to use input validation in a filter so I must to get the json body in a filter. Unfortunately it is not possible to use @RequestBoduy in the filter

Comment: @armin: I understand what you need. Take a look at my EDIT on the answer.

Comment: I tried to read it by getReader() but the problem was that because more than once spring tried to use it, I got an exception which is said that it cant be used more than one time